# Handheld Terminal SD Card error: the file may be in read-only memory, on a write-protected disk or used by another application

Tags: memory, sd-card, read-only, write-protect, micro-sd-card

I have a handheld terminal and I have made the terminal connect to the PC using USB cable.
Also, SD Card is also in the handheld terminal slot.

Till a few days ago, I was reaching the files in SD card, easily delete and add files in it. But nowadays, Nor I can delete any file neither I can add a new file.

I have checked the notch on SD Card, it is unlocked so there is no write-protection.
I have also used Micro SD with its adapter, still same problem occurs! just able to read the files.

now, I started to think it is all about hand held terminal. 
by the way, the handheld terminal's brand is CASIO IT-9000 and It has Windows Mobile 6.0 OS...

any help is appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0):

well, it happens every now and then.. but i think it is because of the handheld's sd card slot problem! it definitely read the sd card , well i can view any time when I plugged in, but writing in it, gotta plug in and out at least twice to achieve to write in then...

so it's a technical problem, i believe... no more to worry about it, then!